# how to read correctly a complex object sent to the back-end

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, spring-boot

EDIT:
after some tips i edited my code and now i created an object witch contains all my datas as i intended to have it, so now i have an object composed of an int and an array of another object that has an array on the inside
here is the code of the objects:

```
export class tempfp{
mesi: fp[] = []
id:number=0;}



export class fp{
arr:number[]=new Array();}
```

this is what i do before to send the data to my backend
(note that the object data has an any type and the object send is a tempfp)

```
async onSubmit() {
console.log("start: \n"+JSON.stringify(this.data))
for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
  let m = new fp();
  Object.assign(m.arr, JSON.stringify(this.data[i]));
  this.send.mesi[i] = m;
}
this.send.id=this.id;
this.efp.postarray(this.send)//i even tried to put in this function this.data instead of this.send
 }}
```

in my back-end i have the same objects, but when i send the datas using an http post it does not read it correctly indeed when i try to manipulate the datas from the back-end i get error 500 in my browser, and if i try to print this thing in my back-end it looks empty

Comment: You could, for example, send a json-object that contains both the `id` and the `array` and then create a corresponding class in the springboot-service representing that request and set it as the handler method's argument.

Comment: @Turing85 i'm going to try it now

Comment: Make sure to configure the handler method in spring-boot to consume content of type `application/json` (`@PostMapping(..., consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`).

Answer (score 0):

A post request can have only one body and you're already passing a body, what you need to do is create a model in java that represent the body you want to pass and then pass it from the front end.

```java
//I like to use lombok's @Data annotation to generate getters setters 
//and default constructor but you can also write them by hand
@Data 
public class MyBody {

   private String eff;

   private int id;

}
```

then in your controller you will accept ad body an instance of this model.

```java
@PostMapping("takearrfp")
public void takearr(@RequestBody MyBody body) {
   String eff = body.getEff();
   int id = body.getId(); //And then do what you want whit this
   efps.readAndSave(eff);
}
```

At this point the only thing remaining to do is passing this model as a body, so you will need to pass as body of the post request an object with the same fields

```js
{
   eff: put something here,
   id: put the id here
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help @fabrizio, i did as you said and now i have another issue, if you want to help me out again i edited the question, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is simple. As the other answer also said you can only pass only one body at a time. so if you want to include the **id** then you have to put it into the body. Just try the below code

```
const  body = {
    id: id,
    arr: arr
    }
const obj = JSON.stringify(body)
```

Then you can read those data from the back end by using the suggested approach from Fabrizio's answer.

Comment: ok so instead of arr i should use this.data for send all the matrik to the backend, right?

Comment: const  body = {
    id: id,
    arr: this.data
    } <--like that? if i try to read the data sent like that i get null...